# How do I create a file in an existing Google Drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have these two functions. One takes a folder name the other takes a folder ID. I can't figure out why the folder ID one gives me "Exception: Invalid argument: parent.mimeType". I'm using the same code in both

> folder.createFile(fileName, content)

I have tried various third parameters like 'text/plain' and others with no results

```
// this works fine but will not work for subfolders plus I know the folderID
// so why bother walking the list of folders
function createOrAppendFile1(folderName, fileName, content) {
  // get list of folders with matching name
  var folderList = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);  
  if (folderList.hasNext()) {
    // found matching folder
    var folder = folderList.next();

    // search for files with matching name
    var fileList = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);

    if (fileList.hasNext()) {
      // found matching file - append text
      var file = fileList.next();
      var combinedContent = content + "\n\n" + file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      file.setContent(combinedContent);
    }
    else {
      // file not found - create new
      folder.createFile(fileName, content); // *** this creates the file without an error
    }
  }
}

// this should be simple and faster since the folderID is known
function createOrAppendFile2(folderID, fileName, content) {
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  let file, combinedContent;

  // search for files with matching name
  let fileList = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);

  if (fileList.hasNext()) {
    // found matching file - append text
    file = fileList.next();
    combinedContent = content + "\n\n" + file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    file.setContent(combinedContent);
  }
  else {
    // file not found - create new
    folder.createFile(fileName, content); // Exception: Invalid argument: parent.mimeType
  }
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current issue, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your current issue and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From both the error message of `Exception: Invalid argument: parent.mimeType` and the situations when `createOrAppendFile2(folderID, fileName, content)` occurs the error while `createOrAppendFile1(folderName, fileName, content)` is used, no error occurs, I guessed that in your situation when you run `createOrAppendFile2(folderID, fileName, content)` with the arguments, the folder of `folderID` might not be the folder.

  - When I tested this, when I used the file ID (for example, it's spreadsheet.) which is the folder id of the valid folder as `folderID`, I confirmed the same error of `Exception: Invalid argument: parent.mimeType`.
  - Unfortunately, in the current stage, when the ID which is not a folder is used with `let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);`, no error occurs.
  - For example, when the invalid folder ID is used, an error like `Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp.` occurs. So, I thought that the ID is a valid ID. But, the ID might be not the folder.

In order to confirm this, how about adding a script for checking whether the value of `folderID` is the ID of the folder? When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function createOrAppendFile2(folderID, fileName, content) {
  const mimeType = DriveApp.getFileById(folderID).getMimeType();
  if (mimeType != MimeType.FOLDER) {
    throw new Error(`Your folder ID "${folderID}" is not folder ID of the folder. MimeType is ${mimeType}.`);
  }

  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  let file, combinedContent;
  let fileList = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
  if (fileList.hasNext()) {
    file = fileList.next();
    combinedContent = content + "\n\n" + file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    file.setContent(combinedContent);
  } else {
    folder.createFile(fileName, content);
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, first, the value of `folderID` is checked whether the ID is the ID of the folder. When the ID is for the folder, the script is run. When the ID is not for the folder, an error occurs.

#### Note:

- By the way, about `found matching file - append text`, if you want to append the text value of `content` to the existing text file, `combinedContent = content + "\n\n" + file.getBlob().getDataAsString();` might be required to be modified to `combinedContent = file.getBlob().getDataAsString() + "\n\n" + content;`.

#### References:

- [getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String))
- [getMimeType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getmimetype)

Comment: The folder in question is of type:

Comment: Sorry I posted that comment too soon as I was switching windows as I was testing. I must have gotten the folder ID wrong originally because when I added your mineType test I copy & pasted the folder ID again to test and it worked. So the original code was fine, I was just passing an invalid folder ID. Many Thanks for your help!!

Comment: BTW, I just saw the Note: in this post. I wanted the most recently added text at the top of the file since it is an error log, and I don't want to scroll to the end. So combinedContent = content + "\n\n" + file.getBlob().getDataAsString(); is what I want

Comment: @gbarnabic Thank you for the information. I apologize for my poor English skill.